# Canvas game loop using rAF getting janky frames with long "Clear frames"

Tags: javascript, performance, google-chrome, canvas, game-engine

I am working on a game/engine in javascript but are getting horrible janky performance. I am doing:

- rAF for the game loop, and have even tried a zero timeout afterwards to try and let the rendering happen.
- The engine is reusing all gameobjects to minimize garbage (though as you see there is still some accumulating due to events and rAF etc).
- The engine can run both 2d canvas and webgl (w. aggregation of sprites using zero height triangles)

As you see the code is running at acceptable speeds but I am getting ginormous clear frames that seem to have arbitrary heights, and they are totally messing up the update speed (fps).

[image: Chrome Timeline when game is running]

Even on the welcome scene with only a background image and only one menuselector sprite I get this effect.

[image: Chrome Timeline at welcome screen]

I have tried disabling the whole game update phase and key input handling without any noticable effect.

Running the game in WebGL mode seem to worsen the effect but it is clearly visible in canvas 2D mode as well.

Please any ideas on how to get rid of or at least figure out what is causing the blank bars and the jankyness.

Chrome version: Version 45.0.2454.85 m
Computer: Dell m3800 workstation

Thanks

Comment: Could you post some relevant code so we can try to watch where it comes from?

Comment: The canvas is 1280x720. If I reduce it to laughable 640x360, it does run better.

Comment: @Kaiido Its alot of code. Anything in perticular you are suspecting?